# Code to create ZipArchive file on PHP is not working, once downloaded file is damaged

Tags: php, upload, php-ziparchive

I am trying this piece of code found on the internet, which helps to **create a ZipArchive with files on PHP**.

I am trying this **on my server**, which is an **AWS EC2 with Linux Ubuntu** where a **web server** is running. I run the following code :

```
<?php 

function createZipAndDownload($files, $filesPath, $zipFileName)
{
    // Create instance of ZipArchive. and open the zip folder.
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $r = $zip->open($zipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE);
var_dump($r); echo "<br>";

    // Adding every attachments files into the ZIP.
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $r = $zip->addFile($filesPath . $file, $file);
var_dump($r); echo "<br>";
    }
    $r = $zip->close();
var_dump($r); echo "<br>";

    // Download the created zip file
    header("Content-type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = $zipFileName");
    header("Content-length: " . filesize($zipFileName));
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    readfile("$zipFileName");
    exit;
}

// Files which need to be added into zip
$files = array('twiglet-1120x720.jpg','22vwqq.jpg','fb4eb7f8aa5431b0b4e26365ebd59933-239x300.jpg');
// Directory of files
$filesPath = 'https://peakon.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/';
// Name of creating zip file
$zipName = 'document.zip';

echo createZipAndDownload($files, $filesPath, $zipName);

?>
```

Then, I have this output :

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

I understand that the ZipArchive is created, but files are not sent inside the ZipArchive. Nevertheless, the file is downloaded once finished and when I want to open it, it's written that **"the file is damaged"** and I can't open it.

Can you help me ? Do you know why it is not working ? I could like to insert theses images inside and download it ? (images are just examples)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`addFile` takes a file system path, not an HTTP URL. There's several ways to fix it but for your case, it might just be easiest to use [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) along with [`addFromString`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfromstring.php). `file_get_contents` *does* accept URLs, weirdly enough. Note that the parameters for `addFromString` aren't in the same order as `addFile`.

```php
$r = $zip->addFromString($file, file_get_contents($filesPath . $file));
```

In the long run, however, I'd recommend downloading the files, checking the results and throwing error messages as needed, but this should get you started at least.

**edit**

The parameter `ZipArchive::CREATE` will only create an archive if it doesn't exist already, so it might actually try opening an existing file and, with your previous attempts, this might result in you opening a corrupt file. Instead, I would recommend using either `ZipArchive::OVERWRITE` to start over, or `ZipArchive::EXCL` to guarantee that an existing file is not touched.

Putting this all together, this code, exactly as-is, works when I test it:

```php
function createZipAndDownload($files, $filesPath, $zipFileName)
{
    // Create instance of ZipArchive. and open the zip folder.
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $r = $zip->open($zipFileName, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
    var_dump($r);
    echo "<br>";

    // Adding every attachments files into the ZIP.
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $r = $zip->addFromString($file, file_get_contents($filesPath . $file));
        var_dump($r);
        echo "<br>";
    }
    $r = $zip->close();
    var_dump($r);
    echo "<br>";

    // Download the created zip file
    header("Content-type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = $zipFileName");
    header("Content-length: " . filesize($zipFileName));
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    readfile($zipFileName);
    exit;
}

// Files which need to be added into zip
$files = array('twiglet-1120x720.jpg', '22vwqq.jpg', 'fb4eb7f8aa5431b0b4e26365ebd59933-239x300.jpg');
// Directory of files
$filesPath = 'https://peakon.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/';
// Name of creating zip file
$zipName = 'document.zip';

createZipAndDownload($files, $filesPath, $zipName);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried as you said, by replacing the code. 

Now the output is :
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)

The last one became false. The .zip is downloading and I still can't open it, it seems that the file is damaged.

Comment: Many thanks for your help and answer :)

I am trying as you wrote the code. But it still doesn't work and the file is corrupted. 

I wonder if the issue could come from the server, php or ZIP version and so on ? 
I'm working on AWS EC2 with 18.04.1-Ubuntu, apache2 server and 7.2 php version.
ZIP is enabled, zip version is 1.15.4, libzip version is 1.1.2